# How do I tell the system that the service has started?

Tags: systemd, python3

I want to run the Python script as a service, the script starts, and works, but the system shows it in the activating state, which is why it constantly restarts

```
systemd[1]: rpi-rf.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

How to tell the system that the script is up and running?
.service:

```
    # systemd unit file for the Python Demo Service


[Unit]

# Human readable name of the unit
Description=Python rpi-rf_receiver


[Service]

# Command to execute when the service is started
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/rpi-rf/rpi-rf_receive

# Disable Python's buffering of STDOUT and STDERR so that output from the
# service shows up immediately in systemd's logs
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Automatically restart the service if it crashes
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

# Our service will notify systemd once it is up and running
Type=notify

# Use a dedicated user to run our service
User=root


[Install]

# Tell systemd to automatically start this service when the system boots
# (assuming the service is enabled)
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from systemd.daemon import notify, Notification

# Send READY=1
notify(Notification.READY)
```

Comment: This fails with: ImportError: cannot import name 'Notification' from 'systemd.daemon' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/systemd/daemon.py)

Comment: Since `notify` expects a string, one might run `notify("READY=1")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding startup items in systemd is complex and cumbersome. To make this more convenient, there is a tool [add_service](https://github.com/DIYer22/add_service) which provides a simple way to quickly add startup item in systemd.

```
pip3 install add_service

python -m add_service [shell_file/cmd] [user (default `whoami`)]
```

Examples:

```
python -m add_service ssh_nat.sh  # by default user is `whoami`
python -m add_service "`which python3` -m http.server 80" root
```